# How to refactor create_function() to migrate to PHP 7.2

Tags: php

I'm having a little issue removing one create_function() in my site to migrate to PHP 7.2. I'm in no way a programmer, but since it's the only line that pose a problem in the entire site, I was thinking that I might solved it.. but it seems that I'm not able to! It's this line of code :

```
else {
    $products_per_page = ot_get_option('shop_product_count', 12);
    add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return ' . $products_per_page . ';' ), 20 );
}
```

I tried this

```
else {
  $products_per_page = ot_get_option('shop_product_count', 12);
    add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', function($cols) {
        return '$products_per_page';}, 20  );
    }
```

And while my site is running, the number of products per page which is set the backend editor of my site does not apply. It shows a number of 10 products per page (I have no idea why 10) rather than the number specified in the back end editor. Any idea why?

Comment: remove the single quotes around the variable. change `return '$products_per_page';` to `return $products_per_page;`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function ($cols) use ($products_per_page) {
    return $products_per_page;
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! It's perfect.

Comment: It’s my pleasure.

Comment: More detail at [Anonymous Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) example#3